# Any way to do a Batch file move operation only when the HDD is idle-ish?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, batch, batch-file, move

I know how to check if a specific program is running like `winrar` which *might* indicate usage on drive `d:` but is there a better way to determine if a drive is relatively idle enough (via `Batch` or other method, invoked from a `Batch file`) to start moving a large file (in a Batch file operating in the background), since simultaneous move operations seem to cripple my computer, probably due to the 100% HDD usage, I'm guessing. Defragmented drive but still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple way could be done in a single line and the best part is that you don't need to time it.  Let the system worry about that.

We want the use the [Start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command with the /LOW priority flag. If you type `start /?` you can see that the /LOW flag actually means IDLE.

Note that disk I/O is your real issue (and not processor load per say) but this should still make a big difference.

Something like:

```
start /Low "Copying files on idle..." cmd.exe /c copy "c:\gigantic_nerd.file" "d:\archive_folder"
```

- we see `start` setting the process priority to idle
- we see `start` setting the title to "Copying files.."
- then `start` starts cmd.exe with the /c flag which tells cmd.exe to exit when it is done.
- everything after "copy blah blah blah" is executed by cmd.exe which is now running at Idle priority.

Keep in mind that you can also use `start` to limit which processors are allowed to be used as well.

**Please note**: This is a good exercise but for most people a $29 256gb SSD drive would make this ***all*** go away. EVEN A ***$14*** 128GB SSD drive would change your life. This is not possible if replacing a huge drive.

**Also note**: OP has a friggan monster of a HDD (24TB) and it ain't getting replaced by an SSD a time soon.

Comment: I take it that `/low` here means low CPU time, or also low everything, including HDD time? Also can't very well replace a 24tb HDD with a SSD.

Comment: HA 24Tb.. WOW.  And yes.. it is funny.  I was updating my answer about disk I/O right as you were asking it.

Comment: Low refers to one of the flags that control the priority class and the creation of the process.  All of them are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags).  If you write code, you can run things with any darned flag you please.

Comment: Ahh one more thing.  IDLE means IDLE.  I believe that it's impossible for the disk to be busy at IDLE with the exception of whatever it has cached internally  or might be doing on the controller.